# ImapX - unable to redownload letter with Message.Download()

Tags: c#, .net, email, imap, imapx

I want to get headers of letters from mailbox and then redownload some letters completely:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (ImapX.ImapClient imap = new ImapX.ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", 993, true))
    {
        if (imap.Connect())
        {
            imap.Login("***************", "***************");
            imap.Behavior.MessageFetchMode = ImapX.Enums.MessageFetchMode.Headers;

            foreach (ImapX.Folder folder in imap.Folders)
                refreshFolder(folder);

            ImapX.Message msg = imap.Folders["INBOX"].Messages[0];
            msg.Download(ImapX.Enums.MessageFetchMode.Full, true);
        }
    }
}

static void refreshFolder(ImapX.Folder folder)
{
    foreach (ImapX.Folder subfolder in folder.SubFolders)
        refreshFolder(subfolder);

    if (folder.Selectable)
        folder.Messages.Download();
}
```

The code above doesn't do what I need - `msg` still has no anything and even lost headers after `msg.Download(ImapX.Enums.MessageFetchMode.Full, true)`. *Now I realized it tried to get data from folder I've last downloaded and it was empty.*

However I managed to get full letter when not downloading messages from other folders:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (ImapX.ImapClient imap = new ImapX.ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", 993, true))
    {
        if (imap.Connect())
        {
            imap.Login("***************", "***************");
            imap.Behavior.MessageFetchMode = ImapX.Enums.MessageFetchMode.Headers;

            /*foreach (ImapX.Folder folder in imap.Folders)
                refreshFolder(folder);*/

            imap.Folders["INBOX"].Messages.Download();
            ImapX.Message msg = imap.Folders["INBOX"].Messages[0];
            msg.Download(ImapX.Enums.MessageFetchMode.Full, true);
        }
    }
}
```

I really see no reason to remember what folder contains specific letter because I just have `Message` object. How to get the rest of letter?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is `msg.DownloadRawMessage ();`, however, it returns a string and does not populate the existing `Message` structure, so you'll have to do:

```
msg = Message.FromEml (msg.DownloadRawMessage ());
```

Comment: Should I do something before? `msg.DownloadRawMessage()` returns empty string and then `Message.FromEml()` throws NotImplementedException

Comment: I'm not very familiar with ImapX, so I don't know. If you were using [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit), this would be a lot easier.

Comment: Your lib is much better one! Thanks